# how to get up row in wordpress with wpdb

Tags: wordpress

I want to compare two prices in my database.
I get a row with any id:

```
$price1 = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->prices WHERE id = 10" );
```

I want to get up the row from this table means I want to get row same bellow but if row by id 9 is deleted it's missing:

```
$price1 = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->prices WHERE id = 9" );
```

How do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. I have a field that common between these two rows and handle width limit parameter in my query.

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE post_id = %d ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2", $post_id);
```